# clone div into the DOM once

Tags: jquery

I have the following code;

```
$('[class*="time-span"]').on('click', function () {
    var modelPanel = $('.model-detail-panel');
    modelPanel.clone().insertAfter('.timeline', this).slideToggle('fast', function () {
        console.log(this);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

The clone part works well, however I only want 'modelPanel' to appear once in the DOM (each time [class*="time-span"] is clicked). At the moment It's being inserted multiple times after every 'timeline' class, resulting in quite a few instances of the div being inserted.

How can I get this to insert only once per click?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
$('[class*="time-span"]').on('click', function () {
    var modelPanel = $('.model-detail-panel');
    modelPanel.clone().insertAfter('.timeline:first', this).slideToggle('fast', function () {
        console.log(this);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: This adds one instance of 'modelPanel', but I have have multiple 'timeline' classes. Clicking on the third adds 'modelPanel' into the first. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

probably because you are cloning based on a `.class`.

you can have several elements with the class `.model-detail-panel`, so you're cloning all of them, not just one.

try cloning based on other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be more specific than inserting after `.timeline` because jQuery will perform the `insertAfter` on every element with a class of `.timeline` that it finds on your page.

Try using a selector that is only found in one place.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a unique selector. The markup is essentially the same class, 'timeline' repeated over and over. I am wanting to add the div 'model-detail-panel' only once, but each time I click 'time-span'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the class.If class will removed than click event will not work or this will instered once only

```
$('[class*="time-span"]').on('click', function () {
    var modelPanel = $('.model-detail-panel');
    modelPanel.clone().insertAfter('.timeline', this).slideToggle('fast', function () {
        console.log(this);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);

 $(this).removeClass("time-span");
    });
});
```